# Rails: Deep duplicate a record with polymorphic children

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

So I'm looking to take and existing DB record and duplicate it.  When I do a simple `.dup` none of the polymorphic assets get duplicated.

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :profile, as: :profileable, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :address,   through: :profile
  has_many :phones,   through: :profile
  has_many :photos,   through: :profile
  has_many :emails,   through: :profile
  has_many :socials,  through: :profile
  has_many :websites, through: :profile
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profileable, polymorphic: true
  has_many :addresses, as: :addressable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :phones, as: :phoneable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :photos, as: :photable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :emails, as: :emailable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :socials, as: :sociable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :websites, as: :websiteable, dependent: :destroy
end
```

For example

```
Contact.new(user_id: 1, profile: User.second.profiles.first.dup).save
```

Does successfully copy  the profile into a new contact for user with an ID of 1.  But the address, phone, photo, email, socials, and website info does not copy over in this example.  How do I copy each dependent child "if" it exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I didn't get a reply; I wrote my own via a little meta-programming:

```
def new_contact_from_existing_profile(user_id, profile_id)
  params = {}
  %w^Address Phone Photo Email Social Website^.each do |poly_child|
    prefix = eval(poly_child).reflect_on_all_associations(:belongs_to).first.name.to_s
    the_type = prefix + "_type"
    the_id = prefix + "_id"
    eval(poly_child).where(the_type.to_sym => "Profile").where(the_id.to_sym => profile_id).each.with_index do |x,i|
      if  params[ eval(poly_child).table_name + "_attributes" ].nil?
        params[ eval(poly_child).table_name + "_attributes" ] = {}
      end
      params[ eval(poly_child).table_name + "_attributes" ][i.to_s] = x.dup.attributes
    end
  end
  Contact.new(
    user_id: user_id,
    profile: Profile.new(
      Profile.find(profile_id).dup.attributes.update params
    )
  ).save
end
```

For anyone else who wants deep duplications I've written a gem that will handle this for you [PolyBelongsTo](https://github.com/danielpclark/PolyBelongsTo)